# Candidate key constraint in Visual Paradigm 12.1

Tags: database, entity-relationship, erd, visual-paradigm, candidate-key

Is there any way to (visually) enforce candidate key constraint on an entity in an entity-relationship diagram in Visual Paradigm 12.1?

For example we have an entity called `Address (street, city, state, zipcode)`. I want to store the attributes `(id, street, city, state, zipcode)` BUT I want to enforce that the combination `(street X city X state X zipcode)` is unique.

> 1 X James avenue X New York X USA X 123 is OK
>
> 2 X James avenue X New York X USA X 123 is NOT OK

This is an example in VP 12.1.

[image]

The problem is it means

```
street is unique AND
zipcode is unique AND
city is unique AND
state is unique
```

It should mean

```
Combination of street AND zipcode AND city AND state is unique.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Visual Paradigm, but AFAICS it doesn't visually distinguish between individual and composite unique constraints.

In addition to properly specifying the composite key for the generated SQL, how about using foreground or background colors to visually associate the components of a composite key?  For example:

[image: Visual Paradigm composite key with coloring]

Oracle's SQL Data Modeler displays a composite key in the same way as Visual Paradigm.  MySQL Workbench does it a little better, showing indices and highlighting its components when the mouse moves over an index:

[image: MySQL Workbench composite key]

Comment: It will not do because the constraint will not be in the SQL when I generate the SQL from the ERD. Moreover, the generated SQL would be incorrect and the problem will show in production (not development). Is there any other tool that can do this natively?

Comment: VP does allow you to specify composite constraints, and the generated SQL should match.  I'm suggesting the use of color in addition to specifying the proper constraints, only as a visual aid.  I updated my answer to clarify, and compare with two other modeling tools.

Comment: How can I specify composite constraints (business candidate keys) in VP 12.1, so that they will be generated into SQL?

Comment: Right-click on an entity | Open specification | Constraints | Add | Unique constraint, then type a name and add the required columns.

Comment: Cheers for the bounty, mate!